# druid overlord process unable to start error "Address already in use"

Tags: installation, local, druid

After installing druid and zookeeper on MacOSX 10.12, I am unable to get the overlord process to run [as instructed](http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/quickstart.html).

```
java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/overlord/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/overlord:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server overlord
```

I get the error that the address is already in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1 quit the app using the port:**
Check to see what application is running on port 8090 (this is the default). Run `lsof -i :8090 | grep LISTEN` to get the resulting pid. Use the pid to see if the application is one you can close `ps -ef pid`. If so, close/kill it. If not, try method 2.

**Method 2 change the druid configuration:**
Use and editor to open and edit the runtime configuration for overlord. Change the default port given to something else, like `8099`.

```
vim conf-quickstart/druid/overlord/runtime.properties
```